# Django object saved while debugging but won't save when code is run without debugging

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using nested serializers and I have overridden the update method of ModelSerializer. A Strange thing is happening when I run the code. If I debug the code line by line, the nested object is updated but if I run the code without debugging, the object is not updated. Here is my update method of serializer -

```
try:
    nested_object_data = validated_data.pop('nested_data')[0]
    nested_object = instance.nested_object.all()

    for (key, value) in nested_object_data.items():
         setattr(nested_object[0], key, value)
    nested_object[0].save()
except KeyError:
    pass


for (key, value) in validated_data.items():
    setattr(instance, key, value)

instance.save()
return instance
```

Thanks a lot for your time and help.